# Haskell: Taking a list of lists and breaking them down to several single lists (not concatenate)

Tags: list, haskell

this is a really basic question I know, I am a begginer in Haskell. So, I am wondering how to "take" the lists from a function like:

```
putStr( f [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]])
```

I don't know if I am expressing this correctly, but I want to create a function f that takes this type:

```
type Matrix a = [[a]]
type IntMat = Matrix Integer
```

and then does some things on each "row" of the matrix, nameley the inner lists.

The thing is, I am not quite sure as to how to address them! :S 
If I am not making ANY sense at all, please ask me to explain!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand, what "thing" do you want to do to the inner lists?

Comment: "does some things" what things? Look into `map` - that's a good function to begin with.

Comment: Say for example, you are trying to find the max of each of the inner lists. Or find their length to use later on. How would you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"find the max of each of the inner lists", "find their length to use later on", both of them can be done with the `map` higher-order function.

```
Prelude> let a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]] :: [[Integer]]
Prelude> map maximum a
[3,6,8]
Prelude> map length a
[3,3,3]
```

If you have a list `M = [a, b, c, d, ...]`, and you want to use a function `f` to transform the list into `N = [f(a), f(b), f(c), f(d), ...]`, then you could use the function `map` (`N == map f M`).

Answer (score 1):

Let `f :: [Int] -> a` be the function that does want you want to do to each row of the `IntMat`.

Then you can apply it to each row of the matrix by using `map`: `putStr $ map f [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]]` passes each element of the list to `f` and returns a a new list, where the first element is the result of `f firstElement`, the second element is the result of `f secondElement`, etc. Map is defined as

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

For example, to increment each element:

```
incElem :: Int -> Int
incElem x = x + 1

incRow :: [Int] -> [Int]
incRow row = map incElem row

incMat :: IntMat -> IntMat
incMat mat = map incRow mat
```

(Note that this would usually be written much more succinctly like `incMat = map . map $ (+1)` - you don't have to understand how this one works when you're starting out, it's just FYI)

Of course the result of `f` doesn't have to be a list. If it's type is `[Int] -> String`, then `map f` is `[[Int]] -> [String]`. Argument and result have to be a list, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `(map . map)`. If I understand you correctly, you want to perform some operation on each element of the sublists and return a new list.

First, lets look at what (map . map) is:

```
Prelude> :t (map . map)
(map . map) :: (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]
```

I think this is pretty self-explanatory.

Lets use it in an example:

```
Prelude> (map . map) (+1) [[1..3],[4..7],[8..10]]
[[2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11]]
```

So, in this case, we're applying the function `(+1)` to each element of the sublists and returning a new list with the same 'shape' as the old one, but with updated elements.

---

Edit: I misunderstood. This operates on the inner-most elements of the nested list, not the nested lists themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take ith row, then you can use the `(!)` operator.

```
Prelude> [[1, 2], [3]] !! 1
[3]
Prelude> [[1, 2], [3]] !! 0
[1,2]
Prelude>
```

If you want to apply any function to every row, then you can use `map`

```
Prelude> map length[[1, 2], [3]]
[2,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `map`.  Eg.:

```
>>> map maximum [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]]
[3,6,8]
```